# Get actual Contact name from phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts, contacts

Suppose I have created a Contact with blank name ("") and entered 2 number

1. 1234
2. 5678

Now I want to retrieve name from this 2 number. My code always gets first number as name if name is empty. How can I get actual name?

I have used this code:

```
    public static String getContactNamefromNumber(Context context,
        String contactNumber) {
    if (contactNumber == null || contactNumber.equals(""))
        return null;
    String name = null;

    Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(contactNumber)),
            new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID},
            null, null, null);
    if (contactLookupCursor != null) {

        if (contactLookupCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                name = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            } while (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        contactLookupCursor.close();
    }

    return name;
}
```

This code always give me first number as name if actual contact name is blank. I want the actual name( it may blank or valid name) not number. If there is anyway to determine name is blank ? this will also solve my problem.

**Added:** 
I also tried below code:

```
    String name ="";
    Cursor nameCur = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] {
                    Long.valueOf(contactId).toString()  }, null);
    if (nameCur != null && nameCur.getCount() > 0 ) {

        nameCur.moveToFirst();
        do {
            name += "" + nameCur.getPosition() + " : ";
            String displayName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (displayName == null) displayName = "";

            String firstName  = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            if (firstName == null) firstName = "";

            String middleName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
            if (middleName == null) middleName = "";

            String lastName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            if (lastName == null) lastName = "";

            name +=  "First: "  + firstName + " Middle: " + middleName + " Last: " + lastName +  "\n";

        }while (nameCur.moveToNext());
        nameCur.close();
    }
```

Here i have used `contactid` to load name but not working for all contacts. For some contacts `nameCur` contain more than one rows(2,3,4,...8 etc). And sometime first row contains blank info . Here is a sample info i get form `nameCur`. For below case i got `nameCur` with size 9.

```
0 : First:  Middle:  Last:
1 : First: Test_Name Middle:  Last: Deb
2 : First:  Middle:  Last:
3 : First:  Middle:  Last:
4 : First:  Middle:  Last:
5 : First: 3 Middle:  Last:
6 : First: com.google Middle:  Last:
7 : First:  Middle:  Last:
8 : First: 2 Middle:  Last:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with some modification. I have added where clause

```
ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
```

and sort order

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME
```

Here is the code i have used:

```
    public static String getActualContactNameByContactId(Context context, long contactId){

    String name ="";

    String whereName =   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + " = ? " + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME;

    // get firstName & lastName
    Cursor nameCur = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    whereName,
                    whereNameParams,
                    sortOrder);
    if (nameCur != null && nameCur.getCount() > 0 ) {

        nameCur.moveToFirst();

        try {           

         nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        //  if (displayName == null) displayName = "";

            String firstName  = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            if (firstName == null) firstName = "";
            //Log.d("--> ", firstName.length()>0?firstName:displayName);

            String middleName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
            if (middleName == null) middleName = "";

            String lastName = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            if (lastName == null) lastName = "";

            name = firstName.trim();


            if (middleName.trim().length() > 0) {
                if (name.length() > 0) {
                    name+= " ";
                }

                name+= middleName.trim();
            }

            if (lastName.trim().length() > 0) {
                if (name.length() > 0) {
                    name+= " ";
                }

                name+= lastName.trim();
            }



        }catch (Exception e){

        }finally {
            nameCur.close();
        }


    }


    return name;

}
```

I have taken only the first row form the `cursor` as multiple row may return.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));

String family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
```

Comment: At first i thought this will work but after some test i figured out that this is not working for my case. anyway thanks for answer.